# unsigned int of the size of a pointer in C

Tags: c

In C, is one of the following `unsigned`/`unsigned short`/`unsigned long`/`unsigned long long` guaranteed on all devices to be of the same size as a pointer `void *`?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. Why do you need this? Why can't you use `void*` or `intptr_t`?

Comment: @Rogue Thanks, I am new(ish) to C. I would like to have a variable store the length of something, and then, in addition, use it in calculations of pointer offset, and I thought it would be nice to know that it does not have to be resized somewhere internally in order to be used as an offset to a pointer.

Comment: So there's a difference between storing a _pointer_ (which must hold a memory address, and may be different on each machine), and just storing the size of an object or some relative offset (which should remain consistent). I don't see a reason you cannot just use `int`/`size_t` in your case (or a `uint32_t` if you're really in need): it will safely store `sizeof(SomeType*)` and the multiplied-in length of your "something", up to a reasonable limit. Careful with arrays! `sizeof(arrayPointer)` will not give you the array length.

Comment: @Rogue Thanks. But say this size variable is of size 32 bit, and pointers are of size 64 bit. This means that when we offset a pointer by this length, the system should do some conversion, but maybe this is not something people worry about, I don't know...

Comment: It very well could. It becomes a matter of considering the extent of what you're working on: would it be a small array of 100-10000 elements? Assuming an 8-byte pointer with byte-addressable memory, that's a memory offset of 80,000 bytes max in our example, and 80,000 fits well within the bounds of a `uint32_t` (0 to 4294967295). Other concerns might be small memory (e.g. microcontrollers) or a larger number of pointers to store (on the order of millions and millions), at least for storing these offsets.

Comment: @Rogue But even if there is no such practical concern, isn't it just more aesthetic/elegant to have the sizes match so when the system adds them it just adds them, without needing to do some conversion?

Comment: By that logic, all numeric values would be 64 bits, and we'd use a lot more memory. A lot of conversions are implicit and happen under-the-hood, all the way down to the assembly instruction level. `size_t` essentially exists for the reason you've outlined: you'll have a machine-dependent type that will resolve correctly for these conditions.

Comment: Re  "*when we offset a pointer by this length, the system should do some conversion, but maybe this is not something people worry about*". Note that pointer arithmetic takes account of the size of the type pointed to. So when you add an offset, it adds (offset * datasize) to the pointer.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, of that I am aware. I meant something like: suppose pointer `p` are 16 bit and my size variable `a` is 8 bit (everything unsigned say). Then if `p = 253`  and `a=4`, we should get `p+a=257` and for that the computer should first convert `a` to a 16 bit by appending 8 zeros, or maybe it has on the hardware level the possibility to add 8 bit thing to 16 bit thing in one hit... But I guess anyway it is not something to worry about, since type safety insures that the compiler will probably do the correct thing unless it can't, in that case throwing a type error

Comment: Write good, clean, idiomatic code implementing algorithms appropriate to the task.  Use an optimizing compiler (with optimization enabled).  Don't be flagrantly wasteful, but for the most part, leave consideration of performance minutia for when you have an actual performance problem. (And then determine *which* minutia to consider by profiling.)

Comment: "...the computer should first convert..." is a **huge** assumption. How do you know the CPU doesn't have the ability to add an 8-bit value to a 64-bit pointer via a simple instruction, or that it's placed the 8-bit value in a very specific location so it can also be used as 64-bit if necessary?

Comment: PSA: Having concerns like this which may relate to performance are natural, but going out of your way to "optimize" things without having a **measurable performance problem** is how you create over-complicated code that is way harder to maintain. I'd be stunned if this kind of simple addition is a bottleneck, especially if that operation is happening under a billion times a minute.

Comment: And if it's the kind of operation that typiclaly happens a lot, the processor is probably designed to make it efficient.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no such guarantee.

But if you want to save pointer as an integer you have special type called `uintptr_t` (or `intptr_t`) which is guaranteed to hold any pointer converted to integer.

> 7.18.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers
>
> 1. The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type,
>    then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare
>    equal to the original pointer:
>    `intptr_t` The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to
>    this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will
>    compare equal to the original pointer:
>    `uintptr_t`
>
> These types are
> optional.

Update:

> use it in calculations of pointer offset, and I thought it would be
> nice to know that it does not have to be resized somewhere internally
> in order to be used as an offset to a pointer

For this you have another type : `ptrdiff_t`

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
> same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;
> the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
> elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its
> type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>`
> header.

Comment: You should mention `uintptr_t` is defined in `stdint.h`

Comment: Thanks, I am new(ish) to C. I would like to have a variable store the length of something, and then, in addition, use it in calculations of pointer offset, and I thought it would be nice to know that it does not have to be resized somewhere internally in order to be used as an offset to a pointer.

Comment: @Sasha use `size_t` to store the length of some C object because that is the type returned by `sizeof`. I'd use that for offsets aswell

Comment: @JeremyP `size_t` is not perfect for offsets. They can be negative as well. `ssize_t` id implemented

Comment: @0___________ true, if your pointer is not to the start of a block. It's not a use-case  have come across much though.

Comment: @0___________ `ssize_t` is a POSIX extension.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question, as it establishes that some compiler implementation can have different sizes, depending on the memory heap (that can be different for different types) to be addressed.

C uses dynamic memory allocated from a single heap (based on the use of `malloc()/free()` functions in the standard library) The first thing that can arise is if different pointer types can ben handled by the same `void *` type.

In an architecture with different pointer types, implementation of `void *` can be a bit more complex than usual, as the `void *` type should be compatible with all, forcing to make assumptions about alignment and size (not only the size is important) and the alignment of the pointed to value.  All these problems have to be solved when you cast (or automatically convert) a `void *` into another pointer type, and will make the compiler to generate the appropiate code to solve and give you an appropiate pointer.  One thing to consider is the *now lost* original pointer type in case a generic conversion to `void *` was made from a different pointer type.

All these things are of course architecture dependant and must be solved by the compiler implementors, in case they arise for some architecture.  It's quite common (in Harvard architectures) that pointers to code are different size than pointers to data.  And don't forget the mesh with segment:offsets we had in old times of MS-DOS and memory models in the PC architecture.